# How to make a Desktop app that runs your .jar file?

Tags: java, terminal, jar

I have this .jar file on my Desktop. I can run it from terminal with `java -jar Desktop/javaProgram.jar`.
How could I make an application that does that for me? From desktop I cannot open the jar file, it says: "The Java JAR file "javaProgram.jar" could not be launched".

The programming language is Java and I am using Mac OS 10.15.7.
`chmod a+x javaProgram.jar` did also not work.

Comment: Are you on Mac? Is the file marked as executable? Maybe `chmod a+x javaProgram.jar` fixes this.